# Unable to get channels of images in cnn

Tags: opencv

there is a dataset in this form

```
images                                              label
C:/Users/Drive/training/real/abs322b.png              0
C:/Users/Drive/training/fake/gd3fsdf.png              1
C:/Users/Drive/training/real/xcs2zxd.png              0
C:/Users/Drive/training/fake/mnm3222.png              1
```

There are 1500 rows.

So, i have randomly tried with some particular image to find its no. of channels

```
 x=Image.open(dataset['image'][1100])
 x.shape
 AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'

 x.ndim
 AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

I want to find the number of channels of first 100 images, how to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` is a `PIL Image`, so you want [Image.size](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#attributes//):

```
print(x.size)
```

Or you can make it a Numpy array and use `shape`:

```
na = np.array(x)
print(na.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mark. But suppose, i need to find that, out of these 1500 images, how many of them have 2,3 or 4 channels,then how to do that

Comment: Write a `for` loop that iterates over the rows of your dataset. Inside, get the size and number of channels of the current image. Increment the corresponding counter. After the loop, print your counter.